# Memory leak while using c++ string

Tags: c++, valgrind

When i run valgrind on below program, it reports memory leak. Can you please explain the cause?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char * arr = (char *) ::operator new(sizeof(char));
    string s = arr;

    return 0;
}
```

1. What exactly happens on line string s = arr? does it make a copy of arr?

Comment: why would you even write that code?! @Aneri: Arr you a pirate? ;-)

Comment: `std::string` will not magically free your array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`valgrind` is right. You call `new` and don't call `delete`, hence you have a memory leak.

When you assign `arr` to `s`, the latter doesn't take ownership of the former; instead, it makes a copy. It is still your responsibility to free `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

`delete arr` at end of your code will handle memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Ownership of `arr` is not passed to `s`, it copies `arr` to `s`'s internal buffer. You should free memory with `delete` operator

Answer (score 1):

I think you assumed `string` will take the ownership of `arr` and it's responsible for `delete` the `arr`. BUT IT IS WRONG.

```
string s = arr;
```

Just copies characters from `arr` until reaching to `\0`. So, you should `delete` `arr` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The **`new[]`** operator in C++ allocates memory dynamically. All such memory must be freed manually, by the programmer. This is done with the **`delete[]`** operator. If you don't delete memory which you allocated with new, you have created a memory leak.

More information on that topic can be found in this [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html).